# VTK: select a single or multiple faces of a object

Tags: vtk

I'm rendering a 3D object from a stl file and would like to use vtk to select one or more faces of the object. Is it possible to do this using vtk? If not, are there alternatives?

If it is possible, how? And how do you extract the selected face(s)? Without the transformations that happened when rotating/moving the object.

Answer (score 0):

VTK is a software toolkit.  You could certainly build an interactive application using VTK to select faces and export that.  Or if you can select faces programmatically, you could write a script to select a set of faces and export those faces.  It would take programming work to do these sort of things.

If you just want an application where you can click on faces and export that subset, I suggest MeshLab (meshlab.net).